# How to print in one row instead of two?

Tags: php

I have a table with reservation information, for example rooms.

The task is, i have to write them out, The problem is in the selection.

If person A booked the second room on 2018-03-12, and person B booked room 16 on the same day, i get two rows intead of just one.

I think this code could be shorter, but this is my logic...

[The result of the code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdzWG.png)

```
$todaysDate = date('Ymd');
$oneWeekLaterDate = date('Ymd', strtotime("+1 week"));

for($todaysDate; $todaysDate<$oneWeekLaterDate; $todaysDate++) {


    $selectRooms = "SELECT room1, room2, room3, room4, room5, room6, room7, room8, room9, room10, room11,
                room12, room13, room14, room15, room16, room17, room18, room19 
                FROM events
                WHERE '$todaysDate'
                BETWEEN start and end - interval 1 day";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $selectRooms);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {

    While ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<table align='center' id='table' border='1'><tr ><td colspan='20'>$todaysDate</td></tr><tr>";
        for ($i = 1; $i < 20; $i++) {
            if ($row['room' . $i] == '1') {
                echo "<td style='background-color:red;color:white'>$i</td>";
            } else {
                echo "<td style='background-color:green;color:white'>$i</td>";
            }
        }
        echo "</tr></table>";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: and how to do that?

Comment: Could you clarify what is the desired result? Do you want just one table or just one row?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/974098/1

Comment: You can't tell, but `bob` and `allen` are on separate lines in the cell: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57391c/7